# OpenAI API giving error: 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: node.js, express, openai-api, http-status-code-429

I am trying to make a request to the openai API with the following code in express nodeJS:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-Fn2EqsTpiUCTKb8m61wr6H8m",
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function callApi() {
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: "Say this is a test",
        max_tokens: 3000,
        temperature: 0,
      });

    console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
}

callApi();
```

The problem is that I keep getting error 429 Too many requests.

Here some more information:

- The API key is correct.
- When I go to my openai account > view API KEY: it shows that the key was never used so I have never been able to make a call. So how is it possibile that I'm getting error Too many requests?
- I have already tried to implement exponential backoff in the function, but it didn't work.

Comment: OpenAi has rate limit a number of request per minute.  It may over your call. https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5955598-is-api-usage-subject-to-any-rate-limits

Comment: I got the same error on my first call. I checked my billing and had not used any of my credit granted.

Comment: Getting the same error. Checked if my API key was being used in the "usage" in open ai's dashboard, it said the api was unused. Dont understand why still getting a 429 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: Getting this error without a specific error message (nothing like `Rate limit reached for default-text-davinci-002 in ...`). Getting the error sometimes, even though I'm way below my limits.

Comment: I am getting the same error `429 Too Many Requests` on first request. The API error persists also if I try again... I am below the rate limit (obviously) and I am below the quota (just checked in the dashboard).

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue. The reason was that I created my API key BEFORE converting my OpenAI account to paid (adding credit card). **Doesn't matter if you only upgrade, you also need to create a new api key entirely.**

I created another API key AFTER I added my credit card and it worked fine!

Comment: This solved it for me after I had just upgraded to a paid account.

Comment: it worked for me after creating 2nd new key

Comment: this is the correct answer for me and it all worked once i regenerated an api key

Comment: This is the way. Add credits first, then create new API key.

Comment: You can keep the old key, but it will work back again after about 48 hours after you add some credit

Answer (score 24):

If you get the same error (429) after April 1st, that means your free trial 18$ (of all accounts registed before April) expired, even you haven't use api key once.

In your API Usage page, you will found like this:

```
GRANT # CREDIT GRANTED  EXPIRES (UTC)
Grant 1 $18.00  Expired 2023-04-01
```

Good news is you can still use official web chat page.

Answer (score 9):

Not for OP, but in my case, the issue was that I needed to provide my organisation Id to the `Configuration` method like this:

```js
import { Configuration } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-xxxx",
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
});
```

You can get the organisation Id from this page: https://platform.openai.com/account/org-settings

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that I started getting this error, in 2024, when OpenAI changed their payment policy to prepaid. They now require you to **load your account with funds before you can use the API**. Everything now works as it was.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue for me. I also had to wait around 5 minutes after I added funds to my account before the API started working again.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error that you have received.

The error `429 Too Many Requests` means that you have exceeded your free $18 in API credits. You can pay for more on the [official website](https://openai.com/api/pricing/).

It's not possible that your key is correct but is not being used when you try to make a request. Double check that you are using the correct key in your code.

Comment: I'm seeing this error on the first request with a brand new API key.

Comment: Well, I just installed Visual ChatGPT Studio and then try a simple question and I immediatelly get this error.  I'm asking in the plugin window within VS 2022

Comment: @WayneSmallman that's strange. Could your IP possibly have exceeded the amount of credits?

Comment: Someone else pointed out that it could be because I authorized with a telephone number that's attached to another account that's expired.