# 429 "Insufficient Quota" error in OpenAI API even though account has paid subscription amount remaining

Tags: openai-api

I have bought API usage quota, however I am still getting insufficient_quota error when I call the API (using javascript). I am calling API at very low rate ~1 call per minute, mostly manual invocation on human click, so its not related to rate limit.

```
{
"message": "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.",
"type": "insufficient_quota",
"param": null,
"code": "insufficient_quota"
}
```

I tried following, after buying $ quota

1. Regenerate key after upgrade (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76069998/7500843)
2. Tried from https://platform.openai.com/playground
3. Tried from API

None of above works for me. Is there any other step I need to follow?

Comment: OpenAI has tiered rate limits (based on how much you have spent), and [additional limits based on these tiers](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers) that restrict the number of requests per day, tokens per minute, and tokens per day.  Are you sure you haven't exceeded these limits? You should be able to review your rate limits from your [account page.](https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: It doesn't help. In the API usage dashboard, I see 0 API invocation. From API response I am still getting 429 "insufficient_quota", even thought I bough quota, regenerated keys, and its been more than 12 hours (so its not propagation delay).

Comment: <In case it helps others> This was an issue with OpenAI. OpenAI folks fixed the issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: How did the OpenAI folks fix the issue? I am facing the same problem. The GPT endpoint works, but the moderation endpoint gives me insufficient_quota error, even though I have enough funds and no usage for months, except a few just a minute ago.